# Files comparison optimization

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to do the files comparison for the huge(10-20 millions) set of records.

**Requirement explanation**:

For the files comparison, there will be two files to do the comparison 
and find the different records.

1. The files type are : `.txt` , `.csv` , `.xlsx` , `.mdb` or `.accdb`
2. The `File 1` can be any type as mentioned in the first point.
3. The `File 2` can be any type as mentioned in the first point.
4. The delimiter for `File 1` or `File 2` are unknown, it may be any from `~^;|`.
5. Each file is having more than `70 columns` in each.
6. `File 1` is older than `File 2` in terms of records. `File 1` may have 10 million and `File 2` may have 10.2 millions of records.
7. Need to create `File 3`, which consists of different records(for example 0.2 million of records from point 6) from `File 1` to `File 2` with the column header.

**My Try**: I have used `SET` for collecting data from both the files(File1 and File2) and done the comparison 
using `for` and `if` condition.

```
import pyodbc
import os.path
import string
import re
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

# Function for Do you want to continue
def fun_continue():
    # If you want to continue
    yesno = raw_input('\nDo you want to continue(Y/N)?')
    if yesno == 'Y':
        fun_comparison()
    else:
        sys.exit()


def fun_comparison():

    # Getting Input Value's
    file1 = raw_input('Enter the file1 name with path:')
    file_extension_old = os.path.splitext(file1)[1]

    #Condition check for the File extension, if it's ACCESS DB then ask for the table name
    if (file_extension_old == ".accdb")  or (file_extension_old == ".mdb"):
        table_name_old = raw_input('Enter table name:')

    file2 = raw_input('Enter the latest file name:')
    file_extension_latest = os.path.splitext(file2)[1]

    #Condition check for the File extension, if it's ACCESS DB then ask for the table name
    if (file_extension_latest == ".accdb") or (file_extension_latest == ".mdb"):
        table_name_latest = raw_input('Enter table name:')

    file3 = raw_input('Give the file name to store the comparison result:')
    print('Files comparison is running! Please wait...')

    # Duration Calculation START TIME
    start_time = datetime.now()

    # Code for file Comparison
    try:
        #Condition check for the ACCESS FILE -- FILE 1
        if (file_extension_old == ".accdb") or (file_extension_old == ".mdb"):
            conn_string_old = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+file1+';'
            con_old = pyodbc.connect(conn_string_old)
            cur_old = con_old.cursor()

            #Getting Column List
            res_old = cur_old.execute('SELECT * FROM '+table_name_old+' WHERE 1=0')
            column_list = [tuple(map(str, record_new))[0] for record_new in res_old.description]
            column_list = ';'.join(column_list)

            #For Getting Data
            SQLQuery_old = 'SELECT * FROM '+table_name_old+';'
            rows_old = cur_old.execute(SQLQuery_old).fetchall()
            records_old = [tuple(map(str,record_old)) for record_old in rows_old]
            records_old = [";".join(t) + "\n" for t in records_old]
            records_old = set(records_old)
            records_old = map(str.strip, records_old)
            #print records_old
        else:
            with open(file1) as a:
                column_list = a.readline()
                column_list = re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", column_list)
                a = set(a)
                sete = map(str.strip, a)
                setf = [re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", s) for s in sete]
                records_old = [";".join(map(str.strip, i.split(";"))) for i in setf]

        #Condition check for the ACCESS FILE -- FILE 2
        if (file_extension_latest == ".accdb") or (file_extension_latest == ".mdb"):
            conn_string_new = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+file2+';'
            con_new = pyodbc.connect(conn_string_new)
            cur_new = con_new.cursor()

            #Getting Column List
            res_new = cur_new.execute('SELECT * FROM '+table_name_latest+' WHERE 1=0')
            column_list = [tuple(map(str, record_new))[0] for record_new in res_new.description]
            column_list = ';'.join(column_list)

            SQLQuery_new = 'SELECT * FROM '+table_name_latest+';'
            rows_new = cur_new.execute(SQLQuery_new).fetchall()
            records_new = [tuple(map(str,record_new)) for record_new in rows_new]
            records_new = [";".join(t) + "\n" for t in records_new]
            records_new = set(records_new)
            records_new = map(str.strip, records_new)
            #print records_new
        else:
            with open(file2) as b:
                column_list = b.readline()
                column_list = re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", column_list)
                b = set(b)
                sete = map(str.strip, b)
                setf = [re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", s) for s in sete]
                records_new = [";".join(map(str.strip, i.split(";"))) for i in setf]

        column_list = column_list.strip()
        column_list = column_list.replace('; ', ';').strip(' ')
        with open(file3, 'w') as result:
            result.write(column_list + '\n')
            for line in records_new:
                if line not in records_old:
                    result.write(line + '\n')

    except Exception as e:
        print('\n\nError! Files Comparison completed unsuccessfully.')
        print('\nError Details:')
        print(e)

    # Duration calculation END TIME
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    # Calling Continue function
    fun_continue()


# Calling Comparison function
fun_comparison()
input()
```

**Problem**:

1. The code is working fine for small records which i did for testing **but** its not optimal for the huge records.
2. System is getting hang.
3. Consuming more memory as shown below in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The code in this question is nowhere near minimal. Does the problem persist if you delete all comments? Does it persist if you hardcode all inputs? Does it persist if you remove all exception handlers? What if you move the main code out of a function? Or use only files instead of databases? In this fashion, reduce the code until removing or simplifying any line would fix your problem. While you're at it, there's also a large amount of code that looks copied and pasted. Use a function there.

Comment: For very large inputs, any nontrivial program will take lots of memory. If every line in your files is just 200B, then you need 5GB just to represent the whole file - and that's without any overhead for Python or useful data structures. First of all, figure out the general algorithm you want to have. For instance, if you can sort the inputs, then you only need to hold the current positions and their values in both files in memory to perform the comparison. Also, you can let the RDBMS do the heavy lifting for you - they can easily sort or remove duplicate entries, and maybe even compare files.

Comment: @phihag "Remove comments" - seriously? How does the presence of comments affect the performance?

Comment: Removing comments doesn't affect performance - that's precisely the point. By cutting down on lines of code to consider, one can arrive at an example that shows just the essence of the problem. As a side effect, the code becomes much more readable.

Comment: **First off:** Why is all your code duplicated? Everything exists two times. Make functions. No, this is not unimportant.  **Second**: Take a look at [the docmentation of sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). There is a more efficient way of finding the difference between two sets. **Third:** You may also want to check out generators/generator comprehensions/set comprehensions to avoid creating and re-creating the same data over and over in memory. Ideally your code should read one record at a time and store it directly in a set, without all those intermediate lists.

Comment: **Lastly** `re.sub(r"[;,|^~]", ";", s)` on CSV files is dangerous. What if `;` is the delimiter in the current file, but `,` is part of the actual data? This regex replace would break it. Think of a better way of dealing with this. Also, use the `csv` module.

Comment: As @phihag explains, the way you're reading your files, 5GB is very plausible memory usage. (Notice that you have to have `b`, `sete`, `setf`, and `records_new` all alive at the same time.) And if that's really 94% of your memory, you're probably pushing your system into swapping, which is where all the CPU is being wasted. So, that memory usage is what you need to optimize.